# What does "Edit removed during grace period" mean?

Tags: discussion

I am pointing to the [revisions page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/14474/revisions) of this questions: what happened here? What do *[Edit removed during grace period]* and *Notice added Insufficient explanation by iandotkelly♦* mean/represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that Liath probably made an edit, and then redacted that edit.

Comment: This does [appear to be the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history).

Comment: @coleopterist why not you self answer it from the link.

Comment: @coleopterist, The answer you linked agrees with DForck42's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The "Insufficient Explanation notice' (a badly named notice when you actually read the text) was added by me because I thought that the question could easily have resulted in simplistic yes / no or opinion answers.

I thought the question was interesting, but answers should attempt to provide references backing up opinion.

As for the edit - I don't know.